# Drupal showing blank page after migrating to a local server

Tags: drupal, iis-7.5, migrating

Firstly some background,..

IVe started a new job as PHP developer with a company that hosts 2 Drupal (6.x) sites.

While I have years of experience in PHP, Drupal ( and indeed off the shelf content management systems in general ) is a new one on me. Still, there is loads of documentation and its not rocket science, so no problems there.

The server environment is IIS (live server 7.0, locally 7.5) IIS is a totally new beast to me too, so it adds to teh learning curve.

I have successfully gotten a clean install of Drupal (7.x) to run locally, so I know the server is up and running correctly

The problem happens when I try to pull down the live site. I have replicated the database locally, and I know that it is connecting, however when I try to run the local site I get a blank page with the following source c ode:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <?include '_inc_head_common.tpl.php';?>
  </head>

  <body id="body">

      <?include '_inc_header.tpl.php';?>
      <?include '_inc_content_3col.tpl.php';?>
      <?include '_inc_footer.tpl.php';?>
  </body>
</html>
```

So it seems that it is getting to a point and no further..

has anyone encountered this before or could someone point me in the direction that I should be looking at?

Thanks

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your PHP configuration on your dev PC. That page is using PHP [`Short Open Tags`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) (`<?` instead of `<?php`) which may not be enabled on your machine. You can find the setting in your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

> and I know that it is connecting,

Did you enter correct new database login information in sites/default/settings.php ? (write protected by default).

Also, it doesn't look like you have the correct source code. This code should be a theme's page.tpl.php file (sites/all/[theme-name]/page.tpl.php or themes/[theme-name]/page.tpl.php.).

We don't use include in this way either. There are predefined names (html.tpl.php, page.tpl.php, node.tpl.php etc that nests automatically) that gets included automagically.

See: http://drupal.org/node/158043
Also, Drupal requires its own .htaccess file placed (or at least the functionality somewhere in a httpd.conf file) in order to handle cleaner URLs and file protection. 
If you can't access a specific URL, e.g. `http://localhost/user` , try `http://localhost/?q=user`